# Why is the subject here “have” instead of has

Tags: verb-agreement

I was reading this article online when I came across this sentence.

> But its emergence has now killed far more people than just Mr. Floyd and **have** put many American cities under a de facto fourth month of house arrest, just as they were carefully opening up

I was reading it, and I couldn’t figure out why the bold verb above
was have instead of has. I’m still learning English so let me know if you guys know. Thanks

Comment: It's simply an error. It ought to be ***has.***

Comment: You are right. The head of the subject NP is the singular "emergence" and hence the verb should be the singular "has" in both coordinates.

Comment: This site is for students of the English language who will be able to recognise grammatical mistakes on the internet.